# Precision and recall of a random classifier

Tags: classification, precision-recall, randomness

My understanding of precision and recall tells me that there is a tradeoff between these two measures: you can improve one at the cost of the other.

However, when I think of a random classifier (on a binary task) that outputs class $1$ with probability $p$, I don't observe any tradeoff.

$Prec= \frac{TP}{TP+FP} = \frac{p \cdot P}{p \cdot P + p \cdot N} = \frac{P}{P + N}$

$Rec = \frac{TP}{TP+FN} = \frac{p \cdot P}{p \cdot P + (1-p) \cdot P} = p$

Hence, precision is constant (it is given by the prevalence of the positive class), and recall is a high as I want it to be.

Is there anything wrong here?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct (asymptotically) under the assumption of an entirely random classifier. I'm not sure how this conclusion is useful, though.

Comment: Wonder what you mean by "asymptotically correct" :)

Comment: Well, I was thinking about how my classifier compares to a random one (I know there are many questions on the issue) and I was expecting some kind of balance between precision and recall, as the one that exists on a ROC curve where when you increase TPR, you automatically increase the FPR (still, for a random classifier). I was then surprised to find out that there is not such a tradeoff in this case: the best random classifier to compare with, when using P-R to measure it, is just the one that classifies as positive with $p=1$, since precision is fixed and $Recall=p$

Comment: Your idea is to control recall to $p$ by predicting a fraction $p$ of the data as positive. This is only reliable when your samples are large enough. For example, when given 2 positive and 2 negative instances and a random classifier, you are not guaranteed to get $0.5$ recall by labelling half the data as positive. Once your samples get large, this does work asymptotically if the classifier is entirely random.

Comment: Oh, I see, yes, of course, we should be talking about something like the "expected recall". Note however, that I am not assuming balanced data: the number of positive ($P$) and negative ($N$) samples are left variable.

Comment: Yes, you are right. That part of my comment was unnecessary. A useful application of this observation is that it allows one to compute a baseline PR curve for a random classifier, similar to the $45^\circ$ line in ROC analysis. Basically, a random classifier which outputs positive with probability $p$ has area under the PR curve equal to $p$.

Comment: Exactly, and that is, surprisingly for me, a flat line! And, since you don't gain anything with lowering recall, all the baselines in that curve are trivially dominated by the classifier where $p=1$.